# nodejs and logging through different modules

Tags: node.js, logging, separation-of-concerns

I'm just interested in the best approach to the following...

I have an app that is split into a few modules for maintenance reasons and separation of concerns. I want to be able to create a log file when my app starts and then using the different modules I have written write to the same log file without it becoming messy and having unneeded code in my exported modules.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) for logging, it can log in a file, db, anything and it has a good documentation. You can use Winston to log messages across all of your modules.

Comment: its getting kind of easy to get lost in the mass of node modules but this is perfect - exactly what i was looking for! well done mate!